# The Sylow subgroups are unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sorry, I'm new on this subject. I faced a question which let me confused with the concept of a Sylow p-subgroup. The p-subgroups of a group are all contained in *the* Sylow p-subgroup? In another words, the Sylow p-subgroups are unique?

Thanks

Comment: If you had bothered to consider the simplest example you could have answered this yourself! Examples, examples, examples!

Comment: @Mariano: Boy do I agree.  An alarmingly large percentage of the basic algebra questions asked on this site could be answered by the OP by looking through the most familiar examples of these structures that they have surely been introduced to.  I am starting to feel that there is a fundamental cognitive problem here that students are not taught to find and use examples to answer their questions.  Can anything be done about this?

Comment: @Pete: I think this is more the fault of the homework than the students. Homework typically asks students to prove universal claims; in my experience, it rarely asks them to prove existential claims. So the standard heuristic is "look for a proof" rather than "look for a counterexample." (But perhaps this is a symptom of the bigger problem that students are not carefully taught about quantifiers...?)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I agree with Quiaochu, in Hungerford's Algebra the book I'm studying there isn't any example of p-subgroups.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I take your point about universal quantifiers being preferred in problems and statements of theorems.  But to be sure, anything which one might identify as "the fault of the students" is also the fault of their teachers and/or the texts that they read.  Either way it's an issue of concern to mathematics instructors....

Comment: I agree that one should become familiar with some examples. In this case, though, some guidance is in order because to get relevant examples one must avoid not only $p$-groups (obviously) but also abelian groups (not so obvious until after some theorems become available). In this case the simplest relevant group is the group of permutations of three objects --- which I recommend to user42912 for contemplation.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I understand your point, but how I could make examples if I have doubts about the definition itself and the book doesn't give any example of p-subgroups?

Comment: @user42912: I have two responses to your comments.  1) An exercise on p. 96 of Hungerford's text asks for the 2 and 3 Sylow subgroups of $S_3$, $S_4$ and $S_5$.  This would have been sufficient to answer the question.  2) The section on p-groups and Sylow theory in Hungerford's text has no examples, which looks bad.  *But* this is a **graduate** algebra text, and p-groups and Sylow theory are usually treated in undergraduate algebra, so I imagine Hungerford views this section as being there for the sake of logical completeness.  Have you not taken an undergraduate level course in algebra?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I'm an undergraduate student ;)

Comment: @Andreas: this discussion, though very interesting to me, is probably getting out of hand and out of place here.  So I'll hazard one more comment: *someone* is making a mistake if there is a student of group theory who does not have the symmetric groups, or at least $S_3$, at their fingertrips from the very beginning.  Some skill is indeed necessary in knowing which examples are relevant: the student who tries finite abelian groups first is going to take a little while to get there, but by looking patiently through the standard examples she will surely learn something!

Comment: @user42912: You didn't answer my question.  Have you already taken an undergraduate course in algebra?  Hungerford's text is not a good choice for someone with no prior exposure to abstract algebra.  In the preface, Hungerford writes "In actual practice, however, an undergraduate course in modern algebra is probably a necessity for most students."

Comment: @PeteL.Clark yes I did, but it was the same book.

Comment: @user42912: Hungerford's *Algebra* was the course text for an undergraduate course in abstract algebra??  In my opinion that's a very unfortunate choice.  In that case I recommend that you acquire a truly undergraduate level algebra text -- there must be some freely available online -- and work out of there for a while.  Joe Gallian has a text which is actually readable by undergraduates, and it is (not coincidentally) very rich in examples.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thank you for the recommendations. I'll read it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark In the last three years in my university the books of undergraduate courses in algebra was respectively Dean, Hungerford, Hugenford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a Sylow subgroup needs not be unique: it is by definition a maximal element in the lattice of $p$-subgroups but it need not be a maximum element. Since all Sylow $p$-subgroups for the same prime are conjugate, a Sylow subgroup is unique iff it is normal.

[For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Examples), when $n$ is odd, the dihedral group of the $n$-gon has $n$ 2-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: I gave the answer +1, but it falls into one of my pet peeves: Serge Lang often called out terminology which was not "functorial with respect to the ideas", I think that terminology should also be grammatically equivariant.  In other (much less pretentious) words, when you change the part of speech of a mathematical term, it should change in a way predictable to any native English speaker....

Comment: Distinguishing between "maximal" and "maximum" in the way you have is (rather standard) but distressing to me.  "Maximum" sounds like the noun form of "maximal".  Even using "maximum" as an adjective in a way you have is somewhat fishy usage, if you think about it.  (Maximum as an adjective is used right next to a noun with the meaning of limiting the scope of the noun: e.g. *maximum element*.  I have never seen it used as a property of a previously identified object in common English.)  I would use a totally different word instead, something like "the top element".

Comment: I like "largest" instead.

Comment: @Qiaochu: that also works, and sounds less jarring at first.  It does rely on a prior understanding of the mathematical distinction here, but I suppose for that matter so does "top element" (to my ear, "top" has some connotation of uniqueness, but maybe not enough) and so would any terminology used for this purpose.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, I've edited my answer a little. I hope it is clearer now. Of course, I'm not a native English speaker, so it's probably not much better. But my usage is standard as you know of course. Wikipedia agrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element.

Comment: Unfortunately, the standard usage of "maximal" and "maximum" is so widespread that I feel compelled to teach it in the relevant courses, whether I like it or not, because students will encounter it elsewhere.  The same goes for many other instances of crummy terminology, like "irreflexive" not being the negation of "reflexive".

Comment: @Andreas: it *is* very standard, and you are doing a good deed by at least tipping students off to its prevalence.  I must admit that I often view people trying to change notation/terminology as tilting at windmills...but sometimes, as now, I can't help myself from doing so.